# Slow NSAttributed String Rendering

Tags: swift, string, performance, rendering

I'm working on an app for text editing, I when I enter more than 10 000 the app is very slow. I run some for loops during typing, but it's should be a big deal. Is it possible to load the text as you scroll down, in chunks, or something else? Like Dispatch etc? I'm working with NSAttributed String

```
        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
    {

        textView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(0.10), range: NSMakeRange(0, textView.attributedText.length))

        let textRange: UITextRange? = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition((textView.selectedTextRange?.start)!, with: UITextGranularity.sentence, inDirection: 1)

        if textRange != nil
        {
            let sentenceRange = textView.rangeFromTextRange(textRange: textRange!)
            textView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(1), range: sentenceRange)
        }

    }

    extension UITextView
{
    func rangeFromTextRange(textRange: UITextRange) -> NSRange
    {
        let location : Int = self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: textRange.start)
        let length : Int = self.offset(from: textRange.start, to: textRange.end)

        return NSMakeRange(location, length)
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code? `Dispatch` and `lazy loading` can be an answer but without your code, I can't tell which will work.

Comment: @Rahul  I updated my question, please check

Comment: I am getting this error `error: value of type 'UITextView' has no member 'rangeFromTextRange'
    let sentenceRange = textView.rangeFromTextRange(textRange: textRange!)
                        ^~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
` It means textView doesn't have any member as `rangeFromTextRange`. I think you are looking for `selectedRange` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview/1618615-selectedrange

Comment: extension UITextView
{
    func rangeFromTextRange(textRange: UITextRange) -> NSRange
    {
        let location : Int = self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: textRange.start)
        let length : Int = self.offset(from: textRange.start, to: textRange.end)
        
        return NSMakeRange(location, length)
    }

Comment: I am not able to find out the exact problem but one solution which I think of is putting two operations inside Dispatch Queue. `DispatchQueue.main.async { let sentenceRange = textView.rangeFromTextRange(textRange: textRange!)
            textView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(1), range: sentenceRange) }`